# Snapshot of elasticsearch using Curator failing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to take a snapshot of ES Index having name of the type `reincarnation.2015.07.21`and store it in Amazon S3 with the below [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html) command:-

```
curator --host locahost --port 9200  snapshot --repository walle_elk_archive indices --older-than 10 --time-unit days --timestring %Y.%m.%d --prefix reincarnation
```

But I am getting the below error:-

```
2015-09-03 17:18:14,938 INFO      Job starting: snapshot indices
2015-09-03 17:18:14,938 WARNING   Overriding default connection timeout.  New timeout: 21600
ERROR: Connection failure.
```

I have added the aws keys in elasticsearch.yaml as shown below. Restarted elasticsearch after that.

```
################################## AWS Cloud  ################################
cloud.aws.access_key: <SomeMixofNumbersandLetters>
cloud.aws.secret_key: <CanOnlyBeObtainedUponCreationOfAccessKeyDon'tLose>
```

AWS Plugin has also been added to ES node and restarted the node after that.

I have created the repo using the below command and it was successful

```
$ curl -XPUT '<hostname>:9200/_snapshot/walle_elk_archive' -d '
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
     "bucket": "my_bucket_name",
     "region": "your_aws_region",
     "access_key": "your_access_key", 
     "secret_key": "your_secret_key" 
  }
}'
```

Can some one let me know

1. What I am doing wrong ?
2. What this Connection Failure mean? Is it curator failing to connect to elasticsearch or elasticsearch failing to connect to S3? I could not find anything in elasticsearch logs.

   - Curator Version 3.3.0
   - ES Version 1.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelt `locahost` in the curator command line... unless this is the real name of the machine where elasticsearch is running, in which case make sure that this machine is accessible from the machine where you run curator by running

```
curl locahost:9200
```

Comment: My bad :( . Thanks imotov :) .